# How to show a "loading indicator" in Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter web app with pages or containers or dialogs.  They all have HTTP API calls to our backend server, these API calls have a complex process that may take 5 or 10 seconds to send back response to the app.  I would like to display a "process indicator" when the user pressed a button (to activate the call) and close the indicator when there is a response from the API call.

If possible, I would like to make a common module so I don't have to repeat lots of codes in different modules around the whole app.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different state management solutions for accomplishing your task. You can try using [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) with cubits, as it is easy to understand and can cover almost all possible cases. Additionally, it is very popular and has numerous video tutorials on YouTube.

You can begin your journey by consulting the official documentation. They also provide a sample case that you can adapt to your own situation:
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial